# Disable matching single quote in Atom Text Editor

Tags: text-editor, matching, atom-editor

How to selectively disable atom from creating a matching single quote and and backtick? This helps in programming in Scheme.

I tried Settings>Package>Bracket Matcher, if I disable *Autocomplete bracket* then it also disables matching brackets and matching double quotes. I want matching brackets and matching double quotes but not matching single quotes.

**EDIT: This feature is now available in Atom.**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The feature that you want is now available. Just delete the quotes from the Autocomplete Characters in Bracket Matcher package settings.

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, disable completely by toggling `Autocomplete Brackets` off. This won't affect the `bracket-matcher:go-to-matching-bracket` functionality (which is awesome).

Answer (score 1):

Edit -> preferences
from left choose packages
there is a search bar at the top search for Bracket-Matcher
then press setting from right side
look foo settings section and in that section look for something called auto Brackets. Uncheck it.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, it's an all or nothing deal (as of version 0.82.0).

Unchecking the "Autocomplete Brackets" box means no autocompleted closing single/double quotes, brackets, backticks, or parentheses.

[image]

You could always [log an issue](https://github.com/atom/bracket-matcher/issues) (search first and make sure one doesn't already exist) and request that this feature be extended.

Comment: on a side note I switched to Emacs and it has the best support for typing code in Scheme.

Comment: I logged an issue on GitHub.

Comment: @VasanthaGaneshK, great! Include a link to the issue you created so others can follow it. Also, please accept my answer if it answered your question. Thanks. :-)

Comment: thanks a lot!, link for the issue: https://github.com/atom/bracket-matcher/issues/236