# How do I make it so that typing a left arrow does not insert a corresponding right arrow in Atom's Rust mode?

Tags: editor, atom-editor

I want to get `<<` in order to do a left shift, but when I type <kbd><</kbd><kbd><</kbd> in the Rust mode, I get `<<>>`.

How can I fix this behavior?

Comment: This isn't really a bug, it's your text editor inserting matching braces/brackets/tags/etc. If you search in your editor's options, you'll probably find an option to disable that behavior.

Comment: I've looked through and tweaked the editor settings, it still gives me a pair of right arrows. What's interesting is that when I type in my cargo.toml file, it works fine. So I conclude that this is a bug with the rust package.

Comment: What rust package do you mean? A Rust package for Atom?

Comment: [Disable matching single quote in Atom Text Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38041248/disable-matching-single-quote-in-atom-text-editor) may be relevant

Comment: I'm using two packages, ide-rust and language-rust. I looked at that solution, but these packages don't have anything that specify brackets, let alone arrows.